# better way to get a list of variable length strings in fortran

Tags: string, list, fortran

After much digging I've cooked up a home brew scheme for what amounts to a list of variable length strings in Fortran.  Its really an array of a custom type that only has one member property which is a variable length string.  The syntax is a little cumbersome and I'm wondering if there is a better way that I have not been able to find.

Here is what I have:

```
! scratch.f90
module string_list

  type t_string
     character(len=:), allocatable :: s
  end type

end module

program main
  use string_list

  implicit none

  integer i
  type(t_string), allocatable :: list(:)

  allocate(list(2))
  list(1)%s = "hi my name is"
  list(2)%s = "slim shady"

  do i=1,2
     print *, len(list(i)%s)
  end do

end program
```

compile with `gfortran scratch.f90 -o scratch`

then:

```
> ./scratch
13
10
```

Comment: I would opine that your approach is the obvious and default one for Fortran.  If we knew more about your usages we might be able to suggest a better (in some sense) approach.  As for the cumbersomeness of the syntax, *meh* I say.

Comment: My usage is that I am reading configuration files line by line. Because of the way I am parsing them and dealing with them it helps to have the file data in a structure that is indexable by line number.  So far this works well for doing that. I suppose I should be grateful that this approach is even possible given the limitations in old fortran

Comment: Search for "Varying Length Character Strings in Fortran, ISO/IEC 1539-2 : 1994(E)".  Sorry for the edit.  You can find an implementation here: http://www.astro.wisc.edu/~townsend/resource/download/code/iso_varying_string_1.2.f90

Comment: If you told us what you would like the syntax to be it might help us suggest something which you think less "cumbersome"

Comment: I suppose less cumbersome would be `list(1) = ...` rather than `list(1)%s = ...`. Maybe it’s not that big of a deal in the grand scheme of things but I have an intuitive sense that there should be a better way probably because having a struct with one member feels like unnecessary complexity. Obviously it is complexity that is serving a purpose in the absence of built in support for this kind of data structure, and perhaps I am showing my bias in what I feel “should” be available having worked mostly in languages where it is available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the comments suggest, your approach might be a good start. To make the syntax easier you could make some type-bound operators and procedures, for example like:

```
module string_list
    implicit none 
    type str
        character(:), allocatable :: s
    contains
        procedure :: assa, get, length
        generic :: assignment(=) => assa
        generic :: operator(-) => get
        generic :: l => length
    end type
contains
    subroutine assa(st,str1)
        class(str), intent(out) :: st
        character(*), intent(in) :: str1
        st%s = str1
    end
    function get(st1) result(str1)
        class(str), intent(in) :: st1
        character(:), allocatable :: str1
        str1 = st1%s
    end
    function length(st1) result(nn)
        class(str), intent(in) :: st1
        integer :: nn
        nn = len(st1%s)
    end
end 

program test
    use string_list, only: str
    implicit none
    type(str), dimension(:), allocatable :: stra
    allocate(stra(2))
    stra(1) = "hello "
    stra(2) = "fortran"
    print*, -stra(1)
    print*, -stra(1)//-stra(2)
    print*, stra(1)%l(), stra(2)%l()
    print*, len(-stra(1)), len(-stra(2))
end
```

The result is

```
 hello 
 hello fortran
           6           7
           6           7
```

This might not be the smartest design, I just tried something out of interest. Here I overloaded the `-` unitary operator to extract the actual string, and `=`for assignment, to avoid the `%s` syntax, and added a more convenient length-function.

Comment: That’s pretty cool. Going to play with it a little bit

Comment: One could go a little further too, and define some *derived-type i/o* procedures.  If one wished to.

Comment: Congrats.  You've re-invented the wheel.  See Varying Length Character Strings in Fortran, ISO/IEC 1539-2 : 1994(E).

Comment: This will want some form of handling of the components not being allocated if it's used in anger.